# Is the record "with" operator supported in CSharpScript?

Tags: c#, roslyn

I am trying to execute the following bit of code in CSharpScript:

```
var script = @"
    public record MyRecord{public int I{get;init;}} 
    var instance = new MyRecord(); 
    instance with {I = 2}";
var result = await CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync(script);
```

This script does not compile:

```
(4,16): error CS1014: A get or set accessor expected
```

When introducing a variable in between it works:

```
var script = @"
    public record MyRecord{public int I{get;init;}} 
    var instance = new MyRecord();
    var newInstance = instance with {I = 2};
    newInstance";
var result = await CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync(script);
```

Is this a bug or is the with operator not properly supported in CsharpScript? Any hint on how to circumvent this?

Comment: You must assign the new value to something. `instance = instance with {I = 2};`

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes The last expression in a CScript can just be an expression, it doesn't have to be a statement. You could end that script with 10+2 and it would return 12. I am with Roland, this *should* probably work the way he expected.

Comment: What version of CSharpScript?

Comment: @canton7 I tested it in LINQPad 6 (.NET 5) with both CSharpScript 3.9 (last official) as well as 3.10.0-3 (last pre-release), both give same error. Also, both work with the second form, with the extra variable.

Comment: In terms of circumvention, you circumvented it yourself already... while an assignment should technically be redundant, adding it and then the variable as an expression would never break anything (assuming your variable name is guaranteed fresh).

Comment: This is probably a quirk of some parser that *might* be specific to CSharpScript, if you add parenthesis around that last line, then that also works: `(instance with {I=2})`

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/records#with-expression  says "A with expression is not permitted as a statement" Might have something to do with it

Comment: @MicroVirus This is **CSharpScript**, the last line can be just an expression and it wil be returned out as the result of calling **Evaluate**. This goes for Olivier as well, the last line there does not have to be a statement.

Comment: Yes, I'm thinkin that the interpreter may put the 'not a statement' above the return value as an expression. Just a guess

Comment: Since simply adding `(...)` around that last line and it compiles and runs as expected makes me guess this is a quirk of some parser. If CSharpScript is not changed to take advantage of the new C# 9 top-level statements, it might just be CSharpScript having extra parsing handling to be able to do both class declarations and statements at the same level, and this parser is getting tripped up by an unknown keyword.

Comment: latest version of CSharpScript. It is quite annoying as we write a lot of fluent APIs with record and then you want to write something like 
builder with {ThisOption = x, ThatOption = y}.Execute(). This does not work either in CSharpScript, it works perfectly in C#

Comment: I would go to the Roslyn github project and file an issue with this specific example and see what they say.

Comment: adding (...) doesn't work. For instance if you write
await (builder with {OptionA = x}).BuildAsync() 
it writes that it doesn't understand await

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes I'm well aware of that -- did you mean to tag someone else?

Comment: Did you try adding (...) around **the whole line**? as in `(await builder with { ... }.BuildAsync())` ?

Comment: Will file an issue on github if no one has a plausible explanation today...

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen when adding around the whole thing, it complains again that it doesn't understand the syntax

Comment: You're right, but this is probably linked to the (mis-)handling of the `with` keyword, as stuffing `await` inside parenthesis in the final expression works just fine in other cases, this: `await Task.Delay(1000)` works just as fine as `(await Task.Delay(1000))`. The circumvention method you've found yourself, introducing a separate variable, seems to be the only viable option right now.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen yes, can confirm that it works. Similarly, in my original example putting `(instance with {I = 2})` works. However, IMO it is really a bug parsing the expression tree. Will file an issue on github. Otherwise, it feels like programming LISP (jokingly the acronym for Lots of Insensible Paranthesis).

Comment: Issue filed here: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/53670